# How do I set the text on my UILabel on one ViewController to pull from another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I created a `UILabel` called `order1label` on my `ThirdViewController`.

I want text to be displayed on that label based on what is decided in my `SecondViewController`.

Below is the code for those two view controllers. When I click on the Submit UIButton in the `SecondViewController`, I expect the `orderType` to change to `Delivery` on the `ThirdViewController`, and I expect that to be reflected in `order1label`, but it is not. It still says `Takeout`.

What am I doing incorrectly? I've been searching for answers for hours and there does not appear to be a simple solution to this extremely simple problem.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController{
    var orderType = "Takeout"

    @IBAction func SubmitOrderClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        orderType = "Delivery"
    }

}
```

Here is the code for my `ThirdViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    var orderTextController = SecondViewController().orderType

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        order1Label.text = orderTextController
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        order1Label.text = orderTextController
    }

    @IBOutlet var order1Label: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: You are creating a *new* `SecondViewController` instance in the `ThirdViewController`. You just need to pass on the required info from the second to the third. For instance, are you using segues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global variable `orderType` in `SecondViewController` like:

```
import UIKit

var orderType = "Takeout"

class SecondViewController: UIViewController{
@IBAction func SubmitOrderClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    orderType = "Delivery"
}

}
```

Here is the code the ThirdViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    order1Label.text = orderType
}

@IBOutlet var order1Label: UILabel!

}
```

Hope this satisfies your requirements. Happy coding.

Comment: That works when I run the program and go to the SecondViewController first, and press the button, and then visit the ThirdViewController. However, if I visit the ThirdViewController first and then click the button on the SecondViewController, I longer see order1Label.text change from "Takeout" to "Delivery" in the ThirdViewController. Why is that? Thanks so much for your help. Please advise.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing that you want to present ThirdViewController when tapping the button on SecondViewController, so you'd need to change the code to:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController{
    var orderType = "Takeout"

@IBAction func SubmitOrderClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    orderType = "Delivery"
    let thirdController = ThirdViewController()
    thirdController.order1Label.text = orderType
    self.present(thirdController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

When you call present, the view controller you specify will load and will enter to viewDidLoad. You'd also need to remove this

```
var orderTextController = SecondViewController().orderType
```

Comment: I think you meant `self.present(thirdController, animated: true)`. Besides the typo in the first arg, keep in mind that `completion` is `nil` by default as well.

Comment: @PauloMattos you're right, I updated the answer, thank you.

Comment: @carlos21 I just ran the code with those changes and I received some sort of runtime error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)". Does anyone know what that is?

Comment: @PauloMattos Also, for this app I would actually prefer not to present ThirdViewController when tapping the button on SecondViewController

Comment: @PauloMattos then how will you see your data on ThirdViewController if don't want to segue there.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma I have tabbed navigation at the bottom of the app that can take the user to ThirdViewController if they need to go there.

Comment: @shampouya my then in your case you should persist data in database because you can visit that controller anytime from anywhere.

Comment: As @TusharSharma correctly mentioned, you should really consider implementing a proper *model* layer as your app grows more complex. Good old MVC is your friend here :-)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is only because the label in thirdController needs to be informed after the text is changed in secondController.
After changed your text by clicking the button, you need to inform the label in thirdController to also change the text.
There are several ways that you can achieve that, delegate, notification, block and so on.
If you have further question about using any of ways above please tell me.